# Rounding error of $\ln(1 + x)$

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, floating-point, rounding-error, machine-precision

I am struggling to understand the theorem 4 in [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html#704) article. From what I understood, the theorem indicates that since we lost precision in calculating $\ln(x+1)$ for small $x$, a more accurate way to calculate such an expression was suggested. I interpreted the given formula as:

Given that $x$ is a very small number, when adding $x$ to $1$ resulted in $1$, $\ln(1+x)$ is approximated to be equal to $x$, otherwise $\ln(1+x)$ is calculated using $\frac{x\ln(x+1)}{(1+x)-1}$. I don't understand how writing the expression as $\frac{x\ln(x+1)}{(1+x)-1}$ is helpful. What is the practical use of this theorem? Can anyone please help clarifying this theorem?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you curious about the first part, the second part, or both? The first part is easy to understand. The second part seems a bit weird to me.

Comment: @lan For the first part I just assumed it is written based on  L'Hospital's Rule.

Comment: That's not really the full story. In the first part they are noting that $\ln(1+x)=x-x^2/2+o(x^2)$ and the sum is alternating. Thus if $0<|x| \leq \epsilon_{mach}$ then $\ln(1+x)$ is equal to $x$ within floating point precision because $x^2/2<\epsilon_{mach} |x|$.

Comment: Is it based on Taylor series?

Comment: Yes. But the point is just that $x-x^2/2 \leq \ln(1+x) \leq x$ if $|x|<1$, and that if $|x|$ is small then $x^2/2$ is way smaller than $|x|$.

Comment: If that were an actual concern in a practical implementation, most math libraries provide the `log1p(x)` function that computes `log(1+x)` correctly for small values of `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reported the theorem wrongly, the given formula was
$$
\log_{improved}(1+x)=\begin{cases}x&\text{when } 1=1\oplus x\\\frac{x\log(1+x)}{(1+x)-1}&\text{else.}\end{cases}
$$
that is, the enhanced formula is used for "medium" (and also "large") values of $x$ that do not vanish under addition of $1$.

As the the Taylor series is $$\ln(1+x)=x(1-x/2+x^2/3-x^3/4\pm\dots)$$
in the case $|x|<\mu$ or $1\oplus x=1$, the relative error between $x$ and $\ln(1+x)$ is smaller than $\mu$.

For the other case denote $\bar x=(1\oplus x)\ominus 1$, then the formula computes
$$
\frac{x\log(1+\bar x)}{\bar x}=x(1-\bar x/2+\bar x^2/3-\bar x^3/4\pm\dots)
$$
so that the relative error
$$
\frac{x\log(1+\bar x)}{\bar x\log(1+x)}-1=\frac{1-\bar x/2+\bar x^2/3-\bar x^3/4\pm\dots}{1-x/2+x^2/3-x^3/4\pm\dots}-1
$$
 is a multiple of $|x-\bar x|<\mu$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have some questions about your explanation: (1) when you wrote I reported the theorem wrongly, is that because I did not wrote the whole enhanced formula or my explanation is wrong?  (2) You wrote :"that is, the enhanced formula is used for "medium.... "  . Are you talking about condition $1 \neq 1\oplus x $? If yes you mean when  $1 =1\oplus x $  this enhanced definition is not applicable?

Comment: (3) I  assumed the main problem occurs when $ = 1\oplus x$ so why we need to define a separate definition in case   $1 \neq 1\oplus x $ .(4) you mentioned $log1p$ in math liberties.  Does these libraries directly apply a math principle such as Taylor series ?  Sorry if my questions sound stupid.

Comment: Yes, in your reporting you switched the cases. When $1=1⊕x$ then you would divide by zero, since then $(1⊕x)⊖1=0$. -- For very small $x$, the linearization is exact enough, the error of the linearization is smaller than the floating point rounding error. The loss of precision happens for $10^{-15}<x<10^{-1}$, since the evaluation of $1⊕x$ loses the last digits of $x$, however these lost digits influence with the same weight as in $x$ the correct result of $log(1+x)=x-x^2/2+x^3/3\mp...$. -- I do not know the internals of `log1p`, only that it is required to give the most correct fl.p. result.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I may need more time to understand the whole picture.

Comment: Another approximation starts from $x=\bar x+e$ so that $$\ln(1+x)=\ln(1+\bar x)+\ln(1+\frac{e}{1+\bar x})\approx \ln(1+\bar x)+\frac{e}{1+\bar x}$$ leading to the computer formula `log(1+x) + (x+(1-(1+x))) / (1+x)` which requires no case distinctions, i.e., is valid for $1⊕x=0$ and $\ne0$.

Comment: I think as you pointed out I was misunderstood. This solution mainly helps for cases that $x$ is small but still  $1 \oplus x \neq 1$.